# If file exists loop +1 until file is not found and save

Tags: excel, vb.net

Below is my code and I am having troubles getting it to loop and add a number until it finds the open spot to save the file

mypath is a placeholder if you test this use one of your paths please

Any help is appreciated!

```
    Dim fileName = "C:\Desktop\Testing"
    Dim fileExtension As String = ".xlsx"
    Dim fileNumber As Integer = +1




    For Each file As String In fileName
        Do
            If Not IO.File.Exists("C:\Desktop\Testing") Then
                _Book.SaveAs("C:\Desktop\Testing")
                _Excel.Quit
                Exit Do
            Else
                'The file does exist, so increment and try the next one
                fileNumber = fileNumber + 1
                _Book.SaveAs("C:\Desktop\Testing")
                _Excel.Quit
            End If
        Loop
    Next
```

Comment: You should split that logic in a Function FindAvailableFile() As String. That way, you won't have trouble called SaveAs at the wrong place and it'll be easy to test.

Comment: How does one do this by chance? If I may ask?

Comment: I've removed the VBA tag - both the syntax and the framework are completely different; VBA has very little to do with VB.NET.

Comment: You update fileNumber, but your code doesn't use it anywhere.  I would assume you would have to update your mypath variable in the loop to use it.

Comment: I'm quite new to vb.net @LarsTech I dont know really know how to go about doing this.

Comment: Edit your question with your mypath variable.  fileName looks like a string, why are you looping over it?

Comment: @LarsTech edited.

Comment: @LarsTech Sorry about that I totally forgot them is this better?

Comment: That's a lousy edit since now your code doesn't compile (strings without quotes?). Anyway, remove the For Each, that makes no sense. Use the System.IO namespace to use Path.Combine to make your file. `Dim basePath As String = "c:\temp" Dim fileName As String = "test" Dim fullName As String = Path.Combine(basePath, fileName & fileNumber.ToString() & fileExtension)` In the "Else" block, just increment the fileNumber. Remove those other two lines.

Comment: `For Each file As String In fileName` This line does nothing but loop through the characters in filename. First C, then :, the \ etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you thought about this at all. You just slapped some code down and posted it. I already commented on the For Each loop. In the If Else, you do the same thing in the If as in the Else except you increment the fileNumber but you never use fileNumber.

Requires `Imports System.IO` at top of file.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Do
        Dim fileToTest = "C:\Desktop\Testing" & FileNum.ToString & ".xlsx"
        If File.Exists(fileToTest) Then
            FileNum += 1
        Else
            SaveExcelFile(fileToTest)
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
Private Sub SaveExcelFile(fullPath As String)
    'Your code to save the file and close excel
End Sub
```

Now on each iteration of the Do loop you will have a new file name to test. When it finds one that doesn't exist then you go to your save code passing the in the new file name.